# How do i make the minecraft player look at a block

Tags: java, math, vector, delay, minecraft

Currently im coding a mod for minecraft. I wanna be able to make the player look at x, y, z coordinates. I also want to be able click at that block at those x, y, z coordinates(and therefore breaking it if the player is near it).

Another problem i have is that i wanna loop through coordinates / block coordinates and look and click at each of them, but i need to put a delay inbetween them without making my game freeze.

I tried some code that has been already suggested on this forum, but the minecraft character is not perfectly looking in the right direction:

```
public void LookAt(double px, double py, double pz) {
        EntityPlayer me = Minecraft.getMinecraft().player;
        World world = me.world;
        int x = (int) me.posX;
        int y = (int) me.posY + 1;
        int z = (int) me.posZ;
        double dirx = x - px;
        double diry = y - py;
        double dirz = z - pz;
        double len = Math.sqrt(dirx * dirx + diry * diry + dirz * dirz);
        dirx /= len;
        diry /= len;
        dirz /= len;
        double pitch = Math.asin(diry);
        double yaw = Math.atan2(dirz, dirx);
        // to degree
        pitch = pitch * 180.0 / Math.PI;
        yaw = yaw * 180.0 / Math.PI;
        yaw += 90f;
        me.rotationPitch = (float) pitch;
        me.rotationYaw = (float) yaw;
    }
```

The code above sorta works as already said, but its not always looking at the same EXACT coordinates when i use the method from another angle/position.

For the delays i already tried using Thread.sleep(), which resulted in Minecraft Freezing. I also tried robot.delay(), (i use robot to emulate a click), but it results in the same. When i dont put a delay, there is no freeze, but it skips to the last set of coordinates in the loop and only breaks that one block.

Comment: 1. You are asking too many things at once. 2. what does it mean not perfectly looking at? for what input/output ... 3. how is the game API working? I assume messaging/event system in which case delays will freeze the game, instead you need to "animate" your stuff on per call/iteration of your mod code basis... so if your code is called repetitively by the game create a global/static state variable that will tell you what you are doing and change your `for` loop into iterative call manner instead (no `for` loop). If your API is different we need to know so how is the game calling your mod?...

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Bukkit API to simplify the plugin code.

If you want to get the block at player looking, you need to use:

```
Block b = player.getTargetBlock(new HashSet<Material>(), 100);
if (b.getState() instanceof Block) {
    // your code
}
```